# bslib theme not coloring page_navbar as expected

Tags: r, shiny, sass, bootswatch, bslib

I'm new to `bslib` and was excited about some of the style options it presents, but I can't seem to get them working right. I was interested to use the `pulse` bootswatch for the purple (https://bootswatch.com/pulse/), but I'm not seeing it ...

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
    title = "why is the background here not purple?",
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "pulse")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    bs_themer()
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Using the `bs_themer` in the top right of the app seems to give inconsistent results, but other bootswatches do sometimes seem to use the primary color as the header background as expected, but the `pulse` theme doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jan would you please undelete your answer? It works fine for me. Please see [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/making-the-switch-from-shinydashboardplus-to-bslib/176061) related post.

Comment: @ismirsehregal The answer is now undeleted. I also think that it should work, however, due to OP's comments I was not clear whether it addresses the issue as given by the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the primary color manually. This works:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
    title = "background is now purple",
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "pulse") |>
        bslib::bs_add_rules(
            rules = "
                    .navbar.navbar-default {
                        background-color: $primary !important;
                    }
                    "
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: but why?  doesn't the primary and other colors get set automatically when specifying to use the bootswatch?  the webpage [link](https://bootswatch.com/pulse/) makes it look like purple navbars are the default?  i'm new to all this, appreciate your help!

Comment: This does not seem to be the case, but without a deeper look one may not can say this. I maybe would not expect the things you see following the link also inside `bslib` in combination with `shiny` without any further specifications.

Comment: also, for me adding this rule seems to work for a second when the app first pops up, but then it changes from purple to teal green.  if i use `bs_themer()` (in the server block), and then its widget to change to another bootswatch and back again to pulse, then the purple sticks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `bg` argument within the `page_navbar()` function. This seems to be the only color related argument.

You can use this to set the nav bar color with a color string ex("purple' or "#44155f")

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "why is the background here not purple?",
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "pulse"),
  bg = "purple"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  bs_themer()
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```